# Guaranteeing a Solr Commit has occurred

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, lucene

I have a Java job that writes documents to Solr using SolrCloud. Input data is transformed into a map of different entities and each entity is then written to the Solr collection corresponding to its entity type.

My code looks like:

```
public void updateSolrDocumentsToCollection(String collectionName, Collection<SolrInputDocument> documents) {
    this.solrClient.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
    updateRequest.add(documents);
    updateRequest.setCommitWithin(100); //100ms
    updateRequest.process(this.solrClient);
}
```

This method is called once for each collection to which I'm writing, and then a final call is made to write one last document to an `audit` collection.

In integration tests, I wait until I can retrieve the document from the `audit` collection, and then retrieve the documents from the entity collections.

**The problem**

I make the assumption that because `audit` is written to last, once I can retrieve from `audit` then I can retrieve from any other collection I've previously written to. However this does not appear to be true. About 1% of the time, an audit document is retrieved, but the tests fail because the other collections do not yet contain their documents.

Even adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` before retrieving documents doesn't help. That's ten times the commit window, so surely I should be guaranteed to see documents?

How can I guarantee that all documents are searchable?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SolrCloud or a Master/Slave configuration? If you have master slave then commitWithin might not work. See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching).

> The commitWithin settings allow forcing document commits to happen in
>   a defined time period. This is used most frequently with Near Real
>   Time Searching, and for that reason the default is to perform a soft
>   commit. This does not, however, replicate new documents to slave
>   servers in a master/slave environment. If that's a requirement for
>   your implementation, you can force a hard commit by adding a
>   parameter, as in this example:

If not, can you try direct `commit()` from your code and see if that works?

You can also check solr logs to see how often your commits are taking place. And if those commits have `openSearcher=true` it means with every commit a new searcher is opened. If you are indexing in bulk, you might benefit keeping this as `false`.

`CommitWithin` issues a softcommit which opens a new Searcher. It might be possible that you are issuing commits every 100ms but openning a new searcher is taking longer than that.

Try increasing your `commitWithin` to say `500ms` or `1000ms` and see if that works.

Comment: It is SolrCloud sorry, I've clarified the question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of uncommitted documents using the [MBean Request Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MBean+Request+Handler) (*/admin/mbeans*). This handler offers programmatic access to the information provided on the Plugin/Stats page of the Admin UI.

Use the param `stats=true` to get stats properties and check for **docsPending** (the number of documents pending for commit) in the "UPDATEHANDLER" category. You can restrict results by category name using param `cat=UPDATEHANDLER`, however it is not possible to access docsPending directly by query (afaik).

Example query :

`https://host.example.com/solr/collectionName/admin/mbeans?wt=json&indent=true&stats=true`

"*/admin/* " handlers are registered implicitly as of Solr 5.0.0, prior versions needs an explicit registration in solrconfig.xml.